# Can I store NULL in a string?

Tags: c, string

I want to perform some lengthy operations on a large file, which will involve lots and lots of seeking. (The current version of the program takes 5 hours and uses fseek at least 15,057,456 times.) As a result, I am hoping to load the file into the ram, and use `char*` instead of `FILE*`. Can I load null characters from the file into the `char*` array if I:

1. Malloc the char array, and store its length separately, and
2. Only use character operations on the array (i.e. `newchar = *(pointertothearray+offset)` ), avoiding operations like `strcpy` or `strstr`?

Comment: At that point, you no longer have a "string" in the C-understanding of it.   You have an array of bytes.   A C-String is an array of bytes that ends with a NULL (and typically only has displayable characters in it).   A non-string array of bytes contains any bytes, including multiple embedded NULLs.

Comment: If you can allocate the memory, that should work.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at memory mapping techniques (mmap on Linux) that might offer good performance in a random-access scenario such as yours.

Comment: It's called `NUL` character, not `NULL`.

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer constant. The null *character* can be referred to as NUL, or as `'\0'`, or as the null character.

Answer (score 6):

You can load the whole file in a dynamic char array (malloc'ed on the heap) even if there are null characters in it : a null character **is** a valid `char`.

But you cannot call it a *string*. A *C string* is from specification of language a null terminated char array.

So as long as you only use offsets, `mem...` functions and no `str...` functions, there is no problems having null characters in a char array.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the entire file's contents into memory.  Essentially this buffer will be a byte stream and not a string.

Comment: How do you know there's enough memory to hold the entire file? The OP did say it was large. (`mmap` might be a solution, assuming it's available.)